# Why is a variable without the 'var' keyword not in the global scope in the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, scope, google-chrome-devtools

Because I am not using the var keyword why is the variable 'local' not in the global scope in the chrome console?

```
function test(){
local = true;
};

console.log(local);//Uncaught ReferenceError: local is not defined
```

Comment: In your snippet, the function hasn't been called/invoked – `test();`. Its body, including the assignment, `local = true;`, won't be evaluated until then.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Lonowski you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply because the test function is never called so the local variable is never created due to which it throws error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will be available once `test()` is invoked